# Markers extended from CircleMarker - How to group, highlite and bind popup?

Tags: javascript, canvas, leaflet, marker

I made a simple script to dispaly custom circle markers on Geojson polygons. But I can't solve the problem with popups and apperance change.

First I'd merged my markers with CustomPoint style into L.leayerGroup. But then I couldn't highlight and show popup while click.

So I turned them into L.featureGroup. But now popup is always the the same for all of the markers and when passing coursor, not the one but all markers from the group are highlited.

[image: When selecting markers]

[image: Popups]

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem? Should I assign my markers to specific Leaflet object/group or convert them ?

This is full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">


<style>


html, body {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
}
#map {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
</style>


<link rel="stylesheet"             
 href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

 <!--Load plugin -->    

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-    
ajax/2.1.0/leaflet.ajax.min.js"></script>   

</head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>


L.Canvas.include({
_updateCustomPoint: function (layer) {
    if (!this._drawing || layer._empty()) { return; }

    var p = layer._point,
        ctx = this._ctx,
        r = Math.max(Math.round(layer._radius), 1);

    this._drawnLayers[layer._leaflet_id] = layer;

   ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y)
    ctx.lineTo(p.x - 0.58 * r, p.y - r)
    ctx.arc(p.x, p.y - 2 * r, r, -Math.PI * 1.161, Math.PI * 0.161)
    ctx.closePath()
    this._fillStroke(ctx, layer)
},




});

var CustomPoint = L.CircleMarker.extend({
_updatePath: function () {
    this._renderer._updateCustomPoint(this);
},

 _containsPoint: function(p) {
    let r = this._radius

    let insideCircle =
        p.add([0, r * 2]).distanceTo(this._point) <= r +     
this._clickTolerance()

    let a = this._point,
        b = a.subtract([0.58 * r, r]),
        c = a.subtract([-0.58 * r, r])

    let insideTriangle = true

    let ap_x = p.x - a.x
    let ap_y = p.y - a.y

    let p_ab = (b.x - a.x) * ap_y - (b.y - a.y) * ap_x > 0
    let p_ac = (c.x - a.x) * ap_y - (c.y - a.y) * ap_x > 0
    let p_bc = (c.x - b.x) * (p.y - b.y) - (c.y - b.y) * (p.x - b.x) > 0

    if (p_ac === p_ab) {
        insideTriangle = false
    }
    if (p_bc !== p_ab) {
        insideTriangle = false
    }
    return insideTriangle || insideCircle
},

});

var myRenderer;



var minZoom = 0,
    maxZoom = 15;

var map = L.map('map', {
    minZoom: minZoom,
    maxZoom: maxZoom
}).setView([49.79, 19], 15);

L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
    continuousWorld: false,
    minZoom: 0,
    }).addTo(map);

myRenderer = L.canvas({ padding: 0.5 });

function style(feature) {
return {
    radius: 13,
    fillColor: 'green',
    color: 'white',
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 1,
    renderer: myRenderer
};
}

function highlightStyle(feature) {
return {
    radius: 13,
    fillColor: 'red',
    color: "#FFCE00",
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.9
};
}

function resetHighlight(e) {
var layer = e.target;
dotStyleDefault = style(layer.feature);
layer.setStyle(dotStyleDefault);
}


function highlight(e) {
var layer = e.target;
dotStyleHighlight = highlightStyle(layer.feature);
layer.setStyle(dotStyleHighlight);

if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera) {
    layer.bringToFront();
}
}         


var Features = "https://api.npoint.io/b3db1a36dc59740cb056";

var featureGroup = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX(Features, {



            onEachFeature: onEachFeature,     

}).addTo(map);



 var markerGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);  
          


function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {


center=layer.getBounds().getCenter()

  if (1 == feature.properties.N) {
     
return new CustomPoint(center, style(feature)).addTo(markerGroup);           
}           
                


markerGroup.on({
    mouseover: highlight,
    mouseout: resetHighlight
});

var popup = '<table style="width:110px"><tbody><tr><td><div><b>Marker: 
</b>    
</div></td><td><div>' + feature.properties.cena +
    '</div></td></tr><tr class><td><div><b>Group:</b></div></td><td> 
 <div>' + feature.properties.area +
    '</div></td></tr><tr><td><div><b>X:</b></div></td><td><div>' +
    '</div></td></tr><tr><td><div><b>Y:</b></div></td><td><div>'  +
    '</div></td></tr></tbody></table>'

markerGroup.bindPopup(popup);


};
```

Comment: Please share your complete code ... The function `highlight` is missing. Your problem looks like that you call `openPopup()` on the layergroup instead of on the marker

Comment: Thank you for reply. I updated full code above.

Comment: hmm I don't see any mistakes. But try to use Leaflet `1.7.1`

Comment: There is a mistake. I want to highlite only one marker not whole group. And the popup is always the same